# Find the derivative of absolute value using the chain rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need help solving this derivative using  the chain rule. I have tried setting $u = -x^2$

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\ |u| &= \frac{d}{dx} \ \sqrt{u^2} \\&= \frac{1}{2}
(u^2)^\frac{-1}{2} \ \bigg(2u\frac{d}{dx} u \bigg) \\&= \frac{1}{|u|} (uu') \end{align*}

Comment: The derivative is not defined at $u=0$.

Comment: Why ? If $u\neq 0$ is it fine ?

Comment: Yes.  The equality is not true for $u=0$.  That was the message of the previous comment.  No worry.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{d|u(x)|}{dx}=\frac{d|u|}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$ by the chain rule.

So, we need only examine the derivative

$$\frac{d|u|}{du}$$

Note that for $u>0$ the derivative is $+1$ while for $u<0$, the derivative is $-1$.

The derivative at $0$ is undefined since the left-sided and right-sided derivatives are not equal.

So, for $u\ne 0$, we can write

$$\frac{d|u(x)|}{dx}=\frac{du(x)}{dx}\times \frac{u}{|u|}$$